# When using Array.Equals() a compilation error is thrown out

Tags: java, arrays

Hi I am new to Java several hrs old to be precise. I am writing the following code and getting the following error-

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>       The method Equals(int[][], int[][]) is undefined for the type Arrays
>       The method deepequals(int[][], int[][]) is undefined for the type Arrays

```
at App.main(App.java:28)
```

The code is as below for reference. Let me know if I am missing anything. Thanks in advance.

```
public class App {
    static final int ROWS=2;
    static final int COLS=2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int bhade[][]=new int[ROWS][] ;
        int bhade2[][]=new int[ROWS][];

        bhade[0]=new int[COLS];
        bhade[1]=new int[COLS];

        bhade[0][0]=1;
        bhade[0][1]=2;
        bhade[1][0]=3;
        bhade[1][1]=4;

        bhade2[0]=new int[COLS];
        bhade2[1]=new int[COLS];

        bhade2[0][0]=1;
        bhade2[0][1]=2;
        bhade2[1][0]=3;
        bhade2[1][1]=4;

        System.out.println(bhade==bhade2);
        System.out.println(bhade.equals(bhade2));
        System.out.println(Arrays.Equals(bhade,bhade2));
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepequals(bhade,bhade2));
    }
};
```

Comment: Just a guess, but if anything, it's probably `Arrays.equals` with a lowercase `e`.

Comment: yup that and `deepEquals` with capital `E` that works for me now

Comment: I don't think this is causing any problems but what's with the semi-colon at the bottom?

Comment: The semi-colon at the bottom is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
System.out.println(Arrays.Equals(bhade,bhade2));
System.out.println(Arrays.deepequals(bhade,bhade2));
```

to

```
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(bhade,bhade2));
System.out.println(Arrays.deepEquals(bhade,bhade2));
```